# Performance of EntryProcessor and keySet(Predicate)

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching, distributed-cache, hazelcast-imap

I have a hazelcast map defined as follows which stores approx. 1 million entries.

```
IMap<Integer, Employee> employeeMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("employeeMap");
```

`employeeObj.isCool()` returns whether a given employee is "cool" or not.

*I need a mechanism to find all cool employees from the `employeeMap`*. I understand that I can do one of the following.

**Option 1**: Call `employeeMap.keySet(predicate);`which will be executed in parallel in each of the members in the cluster and will be joined by the caller using fork/join mechanism.

**Question 1**: However, I think this would load the entry sets in each node into the memory in one-go, before applying the predicate to each of the entries. Please confirm.

**Option 2**: `employeeMap.executeOnEntries(entryProcessor);` where entryprocessor's `process()` method will be as follows.

```
@Override
public Object process(Entry<Integer, Employee> entry) 
{
    return entry.getValue().isBad() ? true : null;
}
```

**Question 2** : I understand that `EntryProcessor` runs in the partition thread. I would like to know whether it would load (deserilaize) all the local entries in the local node in one-go (and store it temporarily) before `process()` method is called.

**Question 3**: I would like to know the best option available (in terms of time and space complexity) and the rationale behind it.

Comment: I have answered this question on the Hazelcast mailinglist.

Comment: @pveentjer, thank you. I have posted my follow-up questions in the mailing list.

Comment: Dinesh's answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hazelcast/EntryProcessor$20and$20keySet(Predicate)/hazelcast/Co19JQhIrKA/JvDF1vl8BAAJ